# Form validation before Submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation, codeigniter-2

I have the  following form that needs to feed into the  database but I would like it to be validated before it can be saved into the  database :

```
<form name="add_walkin_patient_form" class="add_walkin_patient_form" id="add_walkin_patient_form"  autocomplete="off" >

                <div class="form-line">

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Patient Name
                        </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="patientname" id="patientname" required="" value=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Patient Phone Number
                        </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="patient_phone" id="patient_phone" required="" value=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Department
                        </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select name="department" required="" class="department" id="department">
                                <option value="">Please select : </option>
                                <option value="Pharmacy">Pharmacy</option>
                                <option value="Laboratory">Laboratory</option>
                                <option value="Nurse">Nurse</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button name="add_walkin_patient_button" type="submit" id="add_walkin_patient_button" class="btn add_walkin_patient_button btn-info pull-right">
                    Add Walk In Patient
                </button>
            </form>
```

And the  submit is done by a jquery script using the following script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //delegated submit handlers for the forms inside the table
        $('#add_walkin_patient_button').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            //read the form data ans submit it to someurl
            $.post('<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/reception/add_walkin', $('#add_walkin_patient_form').serialize(), function () {
                //success do something

                // $.notify("New Patient Added Succesfully", "success",{ position:"left" });
                $(".add_walkin_patient_form").notify(
                        "New Walkin Patient Added Successfully",
                        "success",
                        {position: "center"}
                );
                setInterval(function () {
                    var url = "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/reception/";
                    $(location).attr('href', url);
                }, 3000);


            }).fail(function () {
                //error do something
                $(".add_walkin_patient_form").notify(
                        "There was an error please try again later or  contact the system support desk  for assistance",
                        "error",
                        {position: "center"}
                );

            })
        })

    });

</script>
```

How can I put form validation to check if input is empty before submitting it into the  script?

Comment: use jquery.validate - http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 3):

I am using javascript to do the validations.
Following is the form code:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="text" id="username">
    <input type="text" password="password">
    <input type="submit" value='Login' name='login'>
</form>
```

To perform validation write a javascript function:

```
<script>
  function checkform(){
    var uname= document.getElementById("username").value.trim().toUpperCase();

    if(uname=== '' || uname=== null) {
      alert("Username is blank");
      document.getElementById("username").backgroundColor = "#ff6666";
      return false;
    }else document.getElementById("username").backgroundColor = "white";

    var pass= document.getElementById("password").value.trim().toUpperCase();

    if(pass=== '' || pass=== null) {
       alert("Password is blank");
       document.getElementById("password").backgroundColor = "#ff6666";
       return false;
     }else document.getElementById("password").backgroundColor = "white";

    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using,

```
<button name="add_walkin_patient_button" type="submit" id="add_walkin_patient_button" class="btn add_walkin_patient_button btn-info pull-right">
       Add Walk In Patient
</button>
```

Here, `submit` button is used for submitting a form and will never trigger click event. Because, submit will be triggered first thus causing the `click` event skip.

```
$('#add_walkin_patient_button').on('click', function (e) {
```

This would have worked if you have used `normal` button instead of `submit` button

```
<input type="button">Submit</button>
```

Now to the problem. There are two solution for it ,

If you use click event, then you should manually trigger submit on correct validation case,

```
<input type="button" id="add_walkin_patient_button">Submit</button>
//JS : 
$("#add_walkin_patient_button").click(function() {
   if(valid){
     $("#form-id").submit();
    }
```

Another option is to use `submit` event;which is triggered just after you click submit button. Here you need to either allow form submit or halt it based on your validation criteria,

```
$("#form-id").submit(function(){
   if(invalid){
     //Suppress form submit
      return false;
   }else{
      return true;
   }
});
```

P.S

And i would recommend you to use [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) as suggested by [@sherin-mathew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2306706/sherin-mathew)

Answer (score 1):

make a javascript validation method (say, validateForm(), with bool return type). add [onsubmit="return validateForm()"] attribute to your form and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent default action.

```
$('#add_walkin_patient_form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

//Validate form and submit
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <style>
            #first{
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        
        <div class="container"><br>
        
            <div class="col-lg-6 m-auto d-block">
                
                <form action="" method="" onsubmit="return validation()" class="bg-light">
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
               
                        <label for="">Title</label>
                        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                      <!-- <input class="form-control" type="text" > -->
                      
                      <select name="title" id="title"  class="form-control"  >
                          <option value=""class="form-control" >Select</option>
                          <option value="Mr" class="form-control">Mr</option>
                          <option value="Mrs" class="form-control">Mrs</option>
                      </select>
                     
                      <span id="tit" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"> </span>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                     
                      <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="firstName">FirstName</label>
                                <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" id="firstName" >
                              <span id="first" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"> </span>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="lastName">LastName</label>
                                <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" id="lastName">
                              <span id="last" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"> </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
        
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Your Email</label>
                        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email">
                      <span id="fillemail" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"> </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            
                                <label for="contact">Your Contact</label>
                                <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number" id="contact">
                              <span id="con" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"> </span>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="password">Your Password</label>
                                        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password">
                                      <span id="pass" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"> </span>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="conPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                                                <span class="text-danger">*</span>
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="conPassword">
                                              <span id="conPass" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"> </span>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label><input type="checkbox"> I accept <a href="form.html">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label><input type="checkbox"> I agree to recieve Email <a href="form2.html">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label><input type="checkbox"> I agree to recieve SMS <a href="form2.html">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
                                          </div>
                                          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SignUp" id="signUp" class="btn btn-success"     autocomplete="off">
    
                </form><br><br>
    
    
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        

            function validation(){
    
                var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
                var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
                var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
                var contact=document.getElementById('contact').value;
                var password=document.getElementById('password').value;
                var conPassword=document.getElementById('conPassword').value;
              var signBut=document.getElementById('signUp');
             
    
    console.log(firstName);

    
                if(title == ""){
                    document.getElementById("tit").innerHTML ="  Please select the title feild first field";
                    return false;
                }
                
//                 if(firstName == "" & firstName.length<=3){
//                     document.getElementById("first").innerHTML =" Please Enter First Name";
//                     return false;
//                     document.getElementById("signUp").addEventListener("click", function(event){
//   event.preventDefault()
// });
//                 }
signBut.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(firstName=="" & firstName<3)
  {
    document.getElementById("first").innerHTML="Please Enter proper Name";
    e.preventDefault();
  }
},false);
             if(lastName == ""){
                    document.getElementById("last").innerHTML =" Please Enter Last Name";
                    return false;
                }
               else if(email ==""){
                    document.getElementById("fillemail").innerHTML="Please Enter Email";
                    
                }
               else if(contact ==""){
                    document.getElementById("con").innerHTML="Please Enter Your Contact";
                    
                }
               else if(password ==""){
                    document.getElementById("pass").innerHTML="Please Enter Your Password";
                    
                }
               else if(conPassword ==""){
                    document.getElementById("conPass").innerHTML="Please Confirm Password";
                    
                }
                
                
            }
        </script>
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don’t just dump a huge block of code as an answer without any explanation. What is this doing? What specifically addresses the OP’s question? And, as this is an old question with four existing answers, how does it vary from those answers? Review the existing answers to get an idea of how to present answers here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use type button
and then eventClick function of jquery