# How to get form values in template before submit the form?

Tags: python, django

I created a form with Django. In this form I have a filefield. How can I find out if the user has filled in this field before the form is submitted? I want to pop up a warning screen if the file didn't load like "Are you sure?".

How can I do that?

This is an example form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Submitbutton>
</form>
```

**model: **

```
class Pdf(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=customer_directory_path, null=True, blank=True)
    document_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Select', choices=CHOICES)
    ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Form validation before Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272509/form-validation-before-submit)

Comment: Please also provide the Django Form you're using in your template. Most likely you're already good by adding the `required` attribute to the corresponding element. As you want this to be evaluated client side this is basically not a Django or Python question, but a HTML or JavaScript one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use django form validation:
[form validation in django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/)

Easiest is to add a function to the form class:

```
def clean__FIELD_NAME(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data.get('FIELD_NAME')
```