# How can I get a django form value and display it back to the user before the form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have done some research...and found a suggestion to create a function on a form to get a field value...[get form value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68128802/how-to-get-form-values-in-template-before-submit-the-form)

I tried this and for some reason I can't get it to work.  I've used the clean function on the form as part of the submit process and that works great.  The difference here is that I'm essentially trying to inspect the field values well before the form gets submitted.  I want the user to click a button and see the values that have been populated in the "approvers" field in this case.  I've got the button working...but can't seem to get the "approvers" value to populate.  It just shows [].

I defined the function on my form...

```
def get_invitee_name(self):
    invitees = self.cleaned_data.get('approvers')
    return invitees
```

But when I try to call the function in my template as

```
{{ invitees }}
```

...nothing shows up.  Do I need to define this as a context variable as well?

Do I have to do this using Javascript instead or is there a way to do this with pure Django/Python?

I'm using a ModelForm if it matters.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form method you defined only makes the value it returns available in the form it itself, not the templates. If you want to get the values of the submitted data before actually submitting it, and you don't to use JavaScript, you can simply have the `Check values` button make a POST request to another view that then returns the values you need as an `HttpResponse` and re-renders the form.

**views**
I'm using `class-based views` simply because I love them.

```py
from django.views.generic import View

class GetValuesView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = YourForm(request.POST) # The form needs to be rendered with all the data that was entered. 
        approvers = request.POST.get("approvers") # or whatever value you gave to its name attribute 
        return render(request, "path-to-template-rendering-your-form", {"form": form, "approvers": approvers})
```

**urls**

```py
urlpatterns = [
... 
path("get-values/", GetValueView.as_view(), name="get-values") 
]
```

**html**
Then inside the form,

```html
<form method="post">
... 
<button type="submit" formaction="{ url 'get-values' }" value="Get values"/>
</form>
```

While this will work, I think it's easier to just use JavaScript instead.

Comment: Thanks so much for the direction!  I’ll give this a shot!  Why do you think Javascript is easier?  Can you pass a Javascript value to get_context so that they can be used as a template value?  I use class based views exclusively because I think they’re awesome and easier to maintain in the long run as well.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  I've played with this approach a bit...but as you mentioned the Javascript may be more appropriate for my use case.  I've gotten most of the way there with Javascript.  I opened up a separate SO for my Javascript use case.  If you can take a peek I'd appreciate it....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77337350/how-do-i-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-my-django-framework-to-be-used-in-templat