# How do I pass a Javascript variable to my Django framework to be used in template or via get_context?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have been working to pass form values to a modal using Django.  I have gotten most of the way there, but I can't quite make out how to connect the two....

Here is my AJAX...

```
     $("#avail").on("click", function(event) {
       var modalavail = document.getElementById("myModalavail");
       var markedCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
       event.preventDefault();
       $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
       $.ajax({
           method: 'get',
           headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
           url: "",
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           cache: false,
           enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
           success: function(resp) {
             modalavail.style.display = "block";
             for (var checkbox of markedCheckbox) {
             console.log(checkbox.value + ' ');
           }
           },
           error: function (request, status, error) {
             console.log(request.responseText);
             showAjaxFormErrors(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
             $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 50);
             },
          });
       });
```

Here is my HTML...

```
  <button class="button209" id="avail">Check Availability</button>

  <div id="myModalavail" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close"></span>
      <img class="logo4" src="/static/images/threecircles.svg">

      <div class="table56">

        {% for entry in form.approvers %}

          <table class="table57">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="title156">Name</th>
                <th class="title118">Available?</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="title156">{{ entry.name }}</td>
                <td class="title117">Yes</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" id="modal-approvers">
      <button type="button" class="button210" id="modalcloseavail">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Obviously, form.approvers is going to give me all of the eligible approvers in my form....However I'm just trying to pass the selected approvers...

This line of code is working flawlessly....

```
  var markedCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
```

It is getting the approvers that are selected in the form....

Here's my form....

```
class DailyPlannerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = NewDailyPlannerEvent
    exclude = [ 'created_by','summary']

def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    start_time = kwargs.pop('start_time', None)
    User = get_user_model()
    super(DailyPlannerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['approvers'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                            queryset=User.objects.exclude(Q(is_active=False)).order_by('last_name','first_name'),required=False)

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(DailyPlannerForm, self).clean()
    approvers = cleaned_data.get('approvers')
```

Here's the model....

```
class NewDailyPlannerEvent(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ("AwaitingResponse","AwaitingResponse"),
    ("Cancelled","Cancelled"),
    ("Declined","Declined"),
    ("Delete","Delete"),
    ("Saved","Saved"),
    ("Scheduled","Scheduled"),
    ("Submitted","Submitted"),
)

STATUS_CHOICES1 = (
    ("Cancel","Cancel"),
)

STATUS_CHOICES3 = (
    ("True","True"),
    ("False","False"),
    ("N/A","N/A")
)

approver_by_department = models.ManyToManyField(Department,related_name="new_daily_planner_event_approver_by_department")
approvers = models.ManyToManyField(User)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='new_daily_planner_event_created_by')
creation_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)
daily_planner_event_creation_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)
daily_planner_event_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
last_update = models.DateTimeField(null=True)        
request_type = models.CharField(choices=REQUEST_TYPE,default="New Daily Planner Event Request",max_length=35)
start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default="Submitted",max_length=20)
submitted = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES3,default="False",null=True,blank=True,max_length=20)
    
class Meta:
    ordering = ["daily_planner_event_name"]
    
def __str__(self):
    return self.daily_planner_event_name
    
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("DailyPlannerEvents:create_daily_planner_event_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

But I can't figure out how to pass this information back to the HTML so that I can loop through the users who are selected and do more querying and I need to do all of this before the form is submitted.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: Can you also include the form that has the checkboxes?

Comment: @McPherson I updated it with the form....I pared it down to just the part that I think is relevant.

Comment: Oh, you're using ModelForms. Neat. I meant the html form. But it's okay. But since you're using a ModelForm, let's see the models (just the `NewDailyPlannerEvent`). I feel you're doing unnecessary work in the ModelForm.

Comment: @McPherson I updated with the model and as far as the form is concerned...I am displaying the modal with the user clicks on the Check Availability button.  So perhaps I need a form on the modal?  Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: Got it. Just one last thing. Would you like to have two seperate buttons: one for submitting the form, another for checking availability? Or do you want to automatically submit the form after closing the modal?

Comment: @McPherson I sincerely appreciate the assistance.  I want this code to just check the availability.  I have a separate button already working fabulously to submit the form when the user is ready....I might get fancier later...but for now just having a button that checks the availability would be outstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy to display the checked values in the HTML without any AJAX request.

First, your HTML. Leave everythis as is but make the following changes:

1. Remove the `for loop` in the html `table`.
2. Empty the table's `tbody`.

Then, add the script:

```js
let modalElement = $("#myModalavail")
modalElement.hide() // hide the modal by default
$("#avail").on("click", ()=>{
    let checkedValues = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked") // They will only be the input tags, without labels
    $("table tbody").html("") // Clear the tbody contents
    for (const element of checkedValues) {
        let label = $(`[for=${element.getAttribute("id")}]`).text()
        let bodyRow = $("<tr>").append($("<td>").text(label)).append($("<td>").text("Yes"))
        $("table tbody").append(bodyRow)
    }
    modalElement.show() // Now show the modal
})
```

This should work as you expect.

But I noticed in your `ModelForm`, you're manually defineing a `queryset` to the `ManyToMany` field. That's unnecessary. Instead, you can do it in the model itself by setting `blank=True` and making use of `limit_choices_to`.

```py
class NewDailyPlannerEvent(models.Model):
    ...
    approvers = models.ManyToManyField(User, limit_choices_to=Q(active=True), blank=True)
    ...
```

Then in the `ModelForm`, you can simply change the widget in the `Meta` class:

```py
class DailyPlannerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = NewDailyPlannerEvent
       exclude = [ 'created_by','summary']
       widgets = {"approvers": forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()}

   def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
       start_time = kwargs.pop('start_time', None)
       super(DailyPlannerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I don't know why you need to override the `init` method though. And you don't need the `clean` method.

Comment: Thanks so much.....Working on testing right now....

Comment: Thanks so much....I have it working...via your suggestion combined with AJAX...I need to do that for other purposes of the form considerations.  By pulling out the loop for the table...I'm not able to get the availability variable.  I was essentially trying to "get" the ID so that I could pass it to the Django template.  Your method allows me to get the checkbox name...But is there a way to pass it to the Django template?  In the #avail pop up was hoping to loop through and query the user schedule.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I had planned to try to get the yes or no variable based on a loop to see if the user was available.  I hardcoded it in my example...I can now display the table...but have no way of interrogating the user ID via a Django template....Is there a way to "pass" the ID to Django?

Comment: I think I understand. Can you share the model that has the 'availability' field?

Comment: Thanks for helping me.  I opened up a separate SO with everything listed here so that we can get to a different approach.  This approach works great, except it doesn't solve my use case exactly.  The other SO that I opened up is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77340222/is-there-a-way-to-pass-javascript-variable-to-django-template-before-form-submit