# Is there a way to pass Javascript variable to Django template before form submit?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to get a selected approver and do a validation check before a form gets submitted in Django...It's turning out to be fairly complicated...I've gotten most of the way there...but can't seem to figure out how to "get" the ID translated in the Django template...I've gotten the ID...but can't seem to make the final connection....

Here's my AJAX...

```
 $("#avail").on("click", function(event) {
   var modalavail = document.getElementById("myModalavail");
   var markedCheckbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
   event.preventDefault();
   $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
   $.ajax({
       method: 'get',
       headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
       url: "",
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       cache: false,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
       success: function(resp) {
         modalavail.style.display = "block";
         for (var checkbox of markedCheckbox) {
         console.log(checkbox.value + ' ');
       }
       },
       error: function (request, status, error) {
         console.log(request.responseText);
         showAjaxFormErrors(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
         $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 50);
         },
      });
   });
```

Here's my HTML...

Check Availability

```
  <div class="table56">

    {% for entry in form.approvers %}

      <table class="table57">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="title156">Name</th>
            <th class="title118">Available?</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="title156">{{ entry.name }}</td>
            {% if not start_conflict or end_conflict or during_conflict %} 
            <td class="title117">Yes</td>
            {% else %}
            <td class="title117">No</td>
            {% endif %} 
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="modal-approvers">
  <button type="button" class="button210" id="modalcloseavail">Close</button>
</div>
```

Here's my form...

```
class DailyPlannerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = NewDailyPlannerEvent
    exclude = [ 'created_by','summary']

def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    start_time = kwargs.pop('start_time', None)
    User = get_user_model()
    super(DailyPlannerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['approvers'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                            queryset=User.objects.exclude(Q(is_active=False)).order_by('last_name','first_name'),required=False)

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(DailyPlannerForm, self).clean()
    approvers = cleaned_data.get('approvers')
```

Here's my model....

```
class DailyPlannerEvent(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ("AwaitingResponse","AwaitingResponse"),
    ("Cancelled","Cancelled"),
    ("Declined","Declined"),
    ("Delete","Delete"),
    ("Saved","Saved"),
    ("Scheduled","Scheduled"),
    ("Submitted","Submitted"),
)

STATUS_CHOICES1 = (
    ("Cancel","Cancel"),
)

STATUS_CHOICES3 = (
    ("True","True"),
    ("False","False"),
    ("N/A","N/A")
)

approver_by_department = models.ManyToManyField(Department,related_name="new_daily_planner_event_approver_by_department")
approvers = models.ManyToManyField(User)
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='new_daily_planner_event_created_by')
creation_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)
daily_planner_event_creation_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)
daily_planner_event_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
last_update = models.DateTimeField(null=True)        
request_type = models.CharField(choices=REQUEST_TYPE,default="New Daily Planner Event Request",max_length=35)
start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default="Submitted",max_length=20)
submitted = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES3,default="False",null=True,blank=True,max_length=20)
```

And I was ultimately planning to do something like in my view....

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DailyPlannerEventView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    start_conflict = DailyPlannerEvent.objects.filter(
                     start_time__range=(dailyplannerevent.start_time,
                                        dailyplannerevent.end_time,approver=user))
    end_conflict = DailyPlannerEvent.objects.filter(
                   end_time__range=(dailyplannerevent.start_time,
                                    dailyplannerevent.end_time,approver=user))
    during_conflict = DailyPlannerEvent.objects.filter(
                      start_date__lte=dailyplannerevent.start_time, 
                      end_date__gte=dailyplannerevent.end_time,approver=user)
    context['start_conflict'] = start_conflict
    context['end_conflict'] = end_conflict
    context['during_conflict'] = during_conflict
    return context
```

My problem area right now is this line in my HTML....

```
{% for entry in form.approvers %}
```

I can't figure out how to "get" the approvers that are selected in the form translated to this line...I've tried to get context...the line as it appears is obviously showing me every entry in my approvers variable...I only want the ones that are selected by the user...and then I want to show if they are "available" in the HTML after the user clicks on the show availability button.

This is fairly complicated by now but I appreciate any thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: This is loaded with opinions on how to design a web API, so it's probably too broad of a question, but what I would generally do is send the whole POST to the server, validate/verify there (which you probably have to do anyway for security/authorization), and then return success or an error structure that your page code can render as detailed errors (somehow; depends on the app).

Comment: There's not much overhead in sending parameter content with a POST that gets ignored because of invalid or incorrect details.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for the feedback.  How would I go about doing what you're suggesting?

Comment: Well, like I said it's not a trivial design matter; it depends on how your framework (Django) does things, how your authorization/validation and error reporting mechanisms work, how your client-side architecture and page layouts and form designs work, etc. There is no single answer (to say the least).

Comment: No, I don't think it's a bad question in a general sense, but it's pretty broad for stack overflow. *edit* in fact it's represents, in a way, very important core parts of designing a web application system, but that's also kind-of why it's over-broad.

Comment: @Pointy Ok thanks for the feedback.  I actually spelled it out in detail for someone else who had been helping me as they had asked all of these specific questions..and that's how I got to this point...They helped me yesterday with a different approach but it wasn't quite what I was shooting for.  I realize it's broad and complicated but I was at a loss as to where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the short answer is what I was looking for...was the APIVIEW...it allows you to show the form values before you submit the form.

I did something like...

```
class AvailabilityCheckView(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        approvers = self.request.GET.getlist('approvers[]')
        start_time = self.request.GET.get('start_time')
        end_time = self.request.GET.get('end_time')
```

And then from there did Ajax to get the values and process them via Jquery to display them to the screen.  I never did figure out how to pass the values to the template directly....I have a suspicion there might be a way...but I haven't found it yet.